# Messaging framework for Silverstripe

Tags: php, messaging, silverstripe

I have been wondering if there is a standard way of doing session based messages in Silverstripe.

For example a module could set a message like `The task has been processed` and then redirect to another page, and the message would be displayed in a small box on that page.

For example Django framework has http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/
Drupal has http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message

I have googled this and found no modules or built in functionality to dot this. It would be good if all apps, even external ones would handle messaging in the same way. Is this just something that is missing in Silverstripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using Session::addToArray($key, $value) (http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/sapphire/control/Session.html#methodaddToArray). Then Session::get($key) to retrieve the value.

Comment: I've ended up patching the SiteTree class and CMS templates. I will submit this patch to silverstripe because I think there should be a *standard* way of doing this.

Comment: My solution works a lot like Form messages. Using `Session::set($name, $var)` like you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a patch to implement this feature, as it really should be in core.

See http://open.silverstripe.org/ticket/6633